# Criteria builder for Two tables

Tags: java, jpa

I am a beginner with JPA.
My query is,
**Select a,b,c FROM Table1 one, Table2 two where one.a=two.a;**
How can i perform this with Criteria builder?

Comment: Why not post WHAT you have tried, and WHAT result you got? and as a minimum the basic entities. Any "beginner with JPA" would have read docs before they do anything so would know that a table is not used in JPQL or Criteria, a CLASS is. This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a department table which contains some number of people .Below is a join example of CriteriaBuilder.

```
 CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Person> query = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
    Root<Department> department= query.from(Department.class);
    Join<Department, Person> people= departent.join("people");
    query.select(people).where(cb.equal(person.get("name"), "Michael"));
```